# Unable to find version of CDP to use for 120.0.6099.217

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Unable to find version of CDP to use for 120.0.6099.217. You may need to include a dependency on a specific version of the CDP using something similar to `org.seleniumhq.selenium:selenium-devtools-v86:4.16.1` where the version ("v86") matches the version of the chromium-based browser you're using and the version number of the artifact is the same as Selenium's.

I am trying to run selenium against a webpage

can you please help solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the relevant parts of your code.  I'm guessing you're talking about java?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.